# Controlling the instantiation of python object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metaprogramming

My question does not really have much to do with sqlalchemy but rather with pure python.

I'd like to control the instantiation of sqlalchemy Model instances. This is a snippet from my code:

```
class Tag(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    query_class = TagQuery
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I want to achieve that whenever an entry is instantiated (`Tag('django')`) that a new instance should be created only if there is not yet another tag with the name `django` inside the database. Otherwise, instead of initializing a new object, a reference to the already existent row inside the database should be returned by (`Tag('django')`).

As of now I am ensuring the uniqueness of tags inside the `Post` Model:

```
class Post(db.Model):

        # ...
        # code code code
        # ...

        def _set_tags(self, taglist):
            """Associate tags with this entry. The taglist is expected to be already
            normalized without duplicates."""
            # Remove all previous tags
            self._tags = []
            for tag_name in taglist:
                exists = Tag.query.filter(Tag.name==tag_name).first()
                # Only add tags to the database that don't exist yet
                # TODO: Put this in the init method of Tag (if possible)
                if not exists:
                    self._tags.append(Tag(tag_name))
                else:
                    self._tags.append(exists)
```

It does its job but still I'd like to know how to ensure the uniqueness of tags inside the Tag class itself so that I could write the `_set_tags` method like this:

```
def _set_tags(self, taglist):
    # Remove all previous tags
    self._tags = []
    for tag_name in taglist:
        self._tags.append(Tag(tag_name))
```

While writing this question and testing I learned that I need to use the `__new__` method. This is what I've come up with (it even passes the unit tests and I didn't forget to change the `_set_tags` method):

```
class Tag(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    query_class = TagQuery
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Only add tags to the database that don't exist yet. If tag already
        exists return a reference to the tag otherwise a new instance"""
        exists = Tag.query.filter(Tag.name==args[0]).first() if args else None
        if exists:
            return exists
        else:
            return super(Tag, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

What bothers me are two things:

First: I get a warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Second: When I write it like so I get errors (I also tried to rename the paramater `name` to `n` but it did not change anything) :

```
def __new__(cls, name):
    """Only add tags to the database that don't exist yet. If tag already
    exists return a reference to the tag otherwise a new instance"""
    exists = Tag.query.filter(Tag.name==name).first()
    if exists:
        return exists
    else:
        return super(Tag, cls).__new__(cls, name)
```

Errors (or similar):

```
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use class method for that.

```
class Tag(Declarative):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, tag_name):
        tag = cls.query.filter(cls.name == tag_name).first()
        if not tag:
            tag = cls(tag_name)
        return tag
```

And then

```
def _set_tags(self, taglist):
    self._tags = []
    for tag_name in taglist:
        self._tags.append(Tag.get(tag_name))
```

As for `__new__`, you should not confuse it with `__init__`. It is expected to be called w/out args, so even if your own constructor asks for some, you should not pass them to super/object unless you *know* that your super needs them. Typical invocation would be:

```
def __new__(cls, name=None): 
    tag = cls.query.filter(cls.name == tag_name).first()
    if not tag:
        tag = object.__new__(cls)
    return tag
```

However this will not work as expected in your case, since it calls `__init__` automatically if `__new__` returns instance of `cls`. You would need to use metaclass or add some checks in `__init__`.

Comment: All of you gave helpful answers that went in the same direction (factory) but yours is the most concrete. Plus you explained the idiosyncrasies of `__new__` so I've checked your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Don't embed this within the class itself.

Option 1.  Create a factory that has the pre-existing pool of objects.

```
tag_pool = {}
def makeTag( name ):
    if name not in tag_pool:
        tag_pool[name]= Tag(name)
    return tag_pool[name]
```

Life's much simpler.

```
tag= makeTag( 'django' )
```

This will create the item if necessary.

Option 2.  Define a "get_or_create" version of the `makeTag` function.  This will query the database.  If the item is found, return the object.  If no item is found, create it, insert it and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the OP's latest error msg:

```
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

it seems that somewhere the class is getting instantiated *without* the `name` parameter, i.e. just `Tag()`.  The traceback for that exception should tell you **where** that "somewhere" *is* (but we're not shown it, so that's how far as we can go;-).

That being said, I agree with other answers that a factory function (possibly nicely dressed up as a `classmethod` -- making factories is one of the best uses of `classmethod`, after all;-) is the way to go, avoiding the complication that `__new__` entails (such as forcing `__init__` to find out whether the object's already initialized to avoid re-initializing it!-).